# FB.ui share poor quality pictures

Tags: php, facebook

i'm using php to generate on the fly a sort of ad/postcard for the users of my site. it works well and it generates a huge lossless image  as png size: 
     2400x1390px

but when i post it to FB using

```
function shareOnWall(link, picture, name, caption, description) {
    FB.ui({
        method: "feed",
        link: link,
        picture: picture,
        name: name,
        caption: '.....www.mysite....' 
    }, shareCallback);
}
```

the image in the post is super low quality! how is it possible?

here some screenshots:

1) output from my script

[image]

2) output from Facebook Debug Tool (lower quality but ok)

[image]

3) actual post on facebook (awful quality)

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the original and what it's generating?

Comment: just updated w/ samples!

Comment: Can you also post some urls, so that we can try to reproduce this issue?